# Pythonにて、引数をループ処理で増やしていく事はできますか？

Tags: python, python3, selenium

Python3.10.2とseleniumを使用しています。

商品コードを入力、表示された在庫数をスクレイピングしてCSVに保存、という流れなのですが、商品数が増えてきたので、ループ処理に変更したく思っています。

ループしたい処理は下記になります。
send_data(n)を1～4000ぐらいまで増やしていく処理ができないか考えています。
なおsend_dataには商品のコードが事前に格納されています。

ご教示のほどよろしくお願いいたします。

```
driver.find_element_by_name("ban01").send_keys(send_data1)
driver.find_element_by_name("ban02").send_keys(send_data2)
driver.find_element_by_name("ban03").send_keys(send_data3)
driver.find_element_by_name("ban11").send_keys(send_data4)
driver.find_element_by_name("ban12").send_keys(send_data5)
driver.find_element_by_name("ban13").send_keys(send_data6)
driver.find_element_by_name("ban21").send_keys(send_data7)
driver.find_element_by_name("ban22").send_keys(send_data8)
driver.find_element_by_name("ban23").send_keys(send_data9)
driver.find_element_by_name("ban31").send_keys(send_data10)
driver.find_element_by_name("ban32").send_keys(send_data11)
driver.find_element_by_name("ban33").send_keys(send_data12)
driver.find_element_by_name("ban41").send_keys(send_data13)
driver.find_element_by_name("ban42").send_keys(send_data14)
driver.find_element_by_name("ban43").send_keys(send_data15)
driver.find_element_by_name("ban51").send_keys(send_data16)
driver.find_element_by_name("ban52").send_keys(send_data17)
driver.find_element_by_name("ban53").send_keys(send_data18)
driver.find_element_by_name("ban61").send_keys(send_data19)
driver.find_element_by_name("ban62").send_keys(send_data20)
driver.find_element_by_name("ban63").send_keys(send_data21)
driver.find_element_by_name("ban71").send_keys(send_data22)
driver.find_element_by_name("ban72").send_keys(send_data23)
driver.find_element_by_name("ban73").send_keys(send_data24)
driver.find_element_by_name("ban81").send_keys(send_data25)
driver.find_element_by_name("ban82").send_keys(send_data26)
driver.find_element_by_name("ban83").send_keys(send_data27)
driver.find_element_by_name("ban91").send_keys(send_data28)
driver.find_element_by_name("ban92").send_keys(send_data29)
driver.find_element_by_name("ban93").send_keys(send_data30)

time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("送信ボタンのxpath").click()
time.sleep(3)
                                                          
list0 =[driver.find_element_by_xpath("商品名0").text, driver.find_element_by_xpath("商品名0の在庫数").text,send_data1,send_data2,send_data3]
list1 =[driver.find_element_by_xpath("商品名1").text, driver.find_element_by_xpath("商品名1の在庫数").text,send_data4,send_data5,send_data6]
list2 =[driver.find_element_by_xpath("商品名2").text, driver.find_element_by_xpath("商品名2の在庫数").text,send_data7,send_data8,send_data9]
list3 =[driver.find_element_by_xpath("商品名3").text, driver.find_element_by_xpath("商品名3の在庫数").text,send_data10,send_data11,send_data12]
list4 =[driver.find_element_by_xpath("商品名4").text, driver.find_element_by_xpath("商品名4の在庫数").text,send_data13,send_data14,send_data15]
list5 =[driver.find_element_by_xpath("商品名5").text, driver.find_element_by_xpath("商品名5の在庫数").text,send_data16,send_data17,send_data18]
list6 =[driver.find_element_by_xpath("商品名6").text, driver.find_element_by_xpath("商品名6の在庫数").text,send_data19,send_data20,send_data21]
list7 =[driver.find_element_by_xpath("商品名7").text, driver.find_element_by_xpath("商品名7の在庫数").text,send_data22,send_data23,send_data24]
list8 =[driver.find_element_by_xpath("商品名8").text, driver.find_element_by_xpath("商品名8の在庫数").text,send_data25,send_data26,send_data27]
list9 =[driver.find_element_by_xpath("商品名9").text, driver.find_element_by_xpath("商品名9の在庫数").text,send_data28,send_data29,send_data30]
with open(r "CSVのパス\zaiko.csv",'a', encoding="shift-jis", newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, lineterminator='\n') 
    writer.writerow(list0)
    writer.writerow(list1)
    writer.writerow(list2)
    writer.writerow(list3)
    writer.writerow(list4)
    writer.writerow(list5)
    writer.writerow(list6)
    writer.writerow(list7)
    writer.writerow(list8)
    writer.writerow(list9)
```

以下は解決済。ありがとうございます。

---

コメントにて返信しましたが、わかりにくかったのでこちらにも追記いたします。
いただいたものを組み込むと以下のエラーとなりました。

```
>>> max = 10#任意の最大値
>>> n = 1
>>> while n<max :
...   n += 1
...
... driver.find_element_by_name("ban01").send_keys(exec("send_data"+str(n)))
  File "<stdin>", line 4
    driver.find_element_by_name("ban01").send_keys(exec("send_data"+str(n)))
    ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

以前にもselenium内で演算などを行うとinvalid syntaxが出た覚えがあります。
当時もdriverに指摘が入っているのがよくわからなった記憶です。
ご教示のほどよろしくお願いいたします

---

現在は以下のエラーと格闘中です。
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

```
>>> MNum = 10
>>> n = 1
>>> while n < MNum :
...   n += 1
...
...   driver.find_element_by_name("ban01").send_keys(exec("send_data"+str(n)))

略

TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

---

さまざまなご提案ありがとうございます。
この問題をややこしくしている、いくつかの情報を追加いたします。

[image: 商品コード入力＆検索結果が帰ってくる画面]

1）ひとつの商品につき、商品コードを3つに分けて入力する仕様になっています。banXXのx1, x2, x3はその並びを意味します。

[image: ソースのキャプチャ]

2)一度に検索できる上限がban0x～ban9xまでの10個になります。

3)ここには記載がありませんが、ID＆PWによるログイン、およびランダム時間でタイムアウトがあり、再ログインの処理があります。

Comment: 回答を基に試して`SyntaxError: invalid syntax`のエラーになったのは、該当の`driver.find_...`の行がインデント無しで入力されているからです。その上の行と同様に行の先頭に空白が2桁入っていれば正常に動作するはずです。

Comment: インデントについては修正しました。ありがとうございます。クォートについては問題なく、正しくcsvに書き出されています。

Comment: 調べてみた所「exec()には戻り値がないため、exec自体は存在しない」とのことでした。戻り地がNoneなので上記のエラーが発生していると思われます。私もあまり詳しくはないのですがexec('driver.find_element_by_name("ban01").send_keys("send_data"+str(n))')とすることで解決できないでしょうか？

Comment: まあ気を付けていませんでしたが、唐突に出てきた`exec()`は何をするためのものでしょう？というのが肝心ですね。そもそも不要なのでは？ [【Python】send_keys・・・キーボード入力をする（通常キー）](https://www.seleniumqref.com/api/python/element_set/Python_send_keys.html), [【Python】send_keys・・・キーボード入力をする(特殊キー)](https://www.seleniumqref.com/api/python/element_set/Python_special_send_keys.html)

Comment: `exec('driver.find_element_by_name("ban01").send_keys("send_data"+str(n))')`など試してみましたが、ban01要素に"send_data1"という文字列（send_data1に格納したデータではない）が入力されるのみでした。evalを試したところ、ban01にsend_data1～のデータが詰め込まれているような挙動（入力上限があるのでそれっぽいとしかいえませんが）でした。このへんでもなにかできないか試してみたいと思います。

Comment: だめでしたか、、、予想にはなりますがevalのほうについては、banの数値を変えていないのでそうなっているだけではないでしょうか？そちらの方のプログラムも作れば改善できるような気がします。2桁の際に0をつけていますが3桁4桁となった際にどういった表示になるのかを教えていただきたいです。

Comment: kunifさんへ```exec()```については私が言い出しました。send_dataや引数までstr型にしてしまっていたのでそれを回避するための案です。

Answer (score 2):

**追加情報を基に全面改訂：**

例えば検索用の3つの情報の組み合わせを`型番,枝番,詳細`といった形でCSVファイルに用意しておき、それを読み込んで処理するという方法が考えられます。
検索用CSVファイル(SearchItems.csv)データ例：

```
型番,枝番,詳細
49123,456789,01
49123,457890,12
49123,458901,23
...以下情報が続く
```

上記を`csv`モジュールで辞書データとして読み込めば、後の処理はループの組み合わせで簡単になるでしょう。
結果のCSVファイル出力も`csv`モジュールで辞書データとして出力すれば良いでしょう。
以下のような形が考えられます。例外処理等は必要に応じて入れてください。
ファイル名は簡略化のために決め打ちですが、コマンドラインパラメータで変えられるようにしておくのも良いでしょう。

```
import csv

with open('SearchItems.csv', 'r', encoding='cp932', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    ItemCodeList = [row for row in reader]

ItemAmount = len(ItemCodeList)
MaxPageItems = 10

ResultHeader = ['商品名', '在庫数', '型番', '枝番', '詳細']

for base in range(0, ItemAmount, MaxPageItems):
    PageItems = ItemCodeList[base:(base + MaxPageItems)]
    PageRows = len(PageItems)
    for n in range(PageRows):
        driver.find_element_by_name(f'ban{n}1').send_keys(PageItems[n][ResultHeader[2]])
        driver.find_element_by_name(f'ban{n}2').send_keys(PageItems[n][ResultHeader[3]])
        driver.find_element_by_name(f'ban{n}3').send_keys(PageItems[n][ResultHeader[4]])
    
    time.sleep(3)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("送信ボタンのxpath").click()
    time.sleep(3)
    
    PageInventory = []
    for m in range(PageRows):
        ItemInventory = {ResultHeader[0]:driver.find_element_by_xpath(f'商品名{m}').text}
        ItemInventory |= {ResultHeader[1]:driver.find_element_by_xpath(f'商品名{m}の在庫数').text}
        ItemInventory |= PageItems[m]
        PageInventory.append(ItemInventory)
    
    with open(r'CSVのパス\zaiko.csv', 'a', encoding='cp932', newline='') as f:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=ResultHeader, lineterminator='\n')
        if f.tell() <= 0:
            writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerows(PageInventory)
    
    #### 複数回にわたる問い合わせ時に、前回の情報をいったんクリアする機能が検索画面に必要と思われる
    time.sleep(3)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("データクリアボタンのxpath").click()
    time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。遅まきながら少々情報を追加いたしました。仕様上、`ItemCodeList`を400個処理することになります。現在は商品が追加されるごとに、最初にご提示したコードの商品コードだけ書き換えたものをマージしていっているのですが、もしかするとシステムの都合を考えるとループ処理にしないほうが良いのかもしれないとも思えてきました。

Answer (score 1):

send_dataの部分のみ抜粋させていただきました。使う際はprint()内を移してexec()などを使ってください。

```py
NumMax = 10#任意の最大値
n = 0
while n<NumMax :
  n += 1
  print("send_data"+str(n))
  print("send_data"+str(3*n-2)+",send_data"+str(3*n-1)+",sand_data"+str(3*n))
```

上の文のsend_dataについては

```
+#文字列及び数値結合
```

と

```
str()#str型に変換(この場合はnをint型からstr型へ)
```

を用いてくっつけてあげることで実現し、下のSend_dataでは上記のことに加えnを3倍した数から一定の数を引いてあげることで実現しています。

わかりにくい説明失礼しました。

---

10/25 16:46追記

```py
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

とのエラーが発生しているとのことですが以下の方法で解決するかもしれません。(コメントで同様の内容を投稿させていただきましたが、より見やすくさせていただきたいと思い追記しました。)
調べてみた所「exec()には戻り値がないため、exec()自体は存在しない」とのことでした。戻り値がNoneなので上記のエラーが発生していると思われます。私もあまり詳しくはないのですが、以下のように文全体を囲んであげることで解決できないでしょうか？

```py
exec('driver.find_element_by_name("ban01").send_keys("send_data"+str(n))')
```

---

18:28追記
上のコードでは動作しなかったそうです。
ご迷惑をおかけしました。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
出てきたエラーが長くなったため、本文に追記させていただきました。
何か糸口となるものでもありましたら、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 回答に提示した部分だけなら動作はしますが、`max`は[組み込み関数](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/functions.html)の名前なので、単純に使用するのは良くないと思われます。質問者さんの新たな状況とは関連していなさそうですが、組み込み関数に加えて[予約語](https://murashun.jp/article/programming/python/python_reserved_word.html)とか[標準ライブラリ](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/index.html)・[PyPI](https://pypi.org/)で配布しているライブラリ等で使われている名前は避けた方が良いでしょう。